# Static analysis of rigid bodies in 3D

Tags: statics

[image]

How to calculate torque due to gravity of a 3D linkage mechanism?  I am performing a static analysis of a Baxter Robot arm. How to calculate the torques at each of the joints ?

Comment: could you please provide context to your question...

Comment: I am performing a static analysis of a Baxter Robot arm. How to calculate the torques at each of the joints ?

Comment: You should think of including a diagram for clarity.

Comment: What are the forces (magnitude, direction, point of application)? Do you know to calculate the torque due to one force?

Comment: I only need to calculate the torque due to gravity. The mass of all the links are known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the total mass $m$ and the center of mass vector $\mathbf{c}$ of all the arms above the motor and use the following equipollent forces and moments to find the reactions.

$$ \begin{align} \mathbf{F} & = m \mathbf{g} \\
\mathbf{M} & = \mathbf{c} \times m \mathbf{g} \end{align} $$ where $\mathbf{g}$ is the acceleration of gravity vector.

Now if the motor joint is along the $\mathbf{z}$ direction and located at $\mathbf{r}$ then to obey the static condition to motor torque $\tau$ has to counter act the moment along the joint axis, or

$$\mathbf{z} \cdot \mathbf{M} + (\mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{z}) \cdot \mathbf{F} = \tau$$

where $\cdot$ is the vector dot product.